# Google checkout Test credit card issue in sandbox

Tags: payment-gateway, shopping-cart, google-checkout

I am using google checkout digital delivery. I have used test credit cards in this link https://developers.google.com/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_HTML_API_Credit_Card_Test_Cases . But for all those credit card, I get same error mail "Your order is on hold: Please update your credit card" and in buyer side and and in seller side I get "The authorization of the customer's credit card failed" message. and after some time I gets "Cancelled by google" message. I cannot test successfull payment using sandbox ?

Comment: I have the same question.  I tested some of this a couple years ago and it worked fine.  Now trying to test the same thing is failing on a new site.  I get the same error as you.  Did you figure anything out?

Answer (score 0):

That was a temporary issue from google's side. Lots of peoples faced the same issue. issue has been resolved automatically after some time..